# iOS get call history with help of PrivateFrameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

During researching of the [PrivateFrameworks](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks) that are available at iOS 9 i found interesting [library](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/CallHistory.framework) that could give access to the call history of the jailbreak iPhone. The question is how to use this framework?

Brief example of my :

```
 NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CallHistory.framework"];
    BOOL success = [b load];

    if (success) {
        Class CallHistoryDBHandle = NSClassFromString(@"CallHistoryDBClientHandle");
        SEL theSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"fetchAllNoLimit");
        id si = [CallHistoryDBHandle valueForKey:@"createForClient"];
        NSLog(@"-- %@", [si performSelector:theSelector]);
    } else {
         NSLog(@"NO");
    }
```

Comment: You may want to check some of the jailbreak fora.  I am not familiar with them myself, but you'll find a more particular audience with this kind of knowledge.

Comment: It will be much easier to just use SQLite to open the database. Call history database has very basic structure. Reversing private APIs can be difficult, they're not always straightforward to use.